# Haskell Currying Simple Example

Tags: haskell, currying

I have defined a Function minCurr:

```
minCur a = (\b -> if a > b then b else a)
```

When asking for the type of minCur I get

```
minCur :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

What I expected is something like

```
minCur :: Ord a => a -> (a->a)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

`a -> b -> c` is exactly the same type as `a -> (b -> c)`. When printing the type, parentheses are omitted for improving readability.

`(a -> b) -> c` instead is always printed with parentheses, otherwise it could be confused with the other type.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, `->` is what we call 'right associative', meaning these two things are equivalent:

```
foo :: a -> (b -> c)
foo :: a -> b -> c
```

In other words, when the compiler sees `minCur :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`, it reads `minCur :: Ord a => a -> (a -> a)` as you expected. So, your expectation was correct and was actually fufilled.

This is done for readability and ease of writing, since putting on more brackets every time you need a new argument is tiresome.

Comment: what is if I have an example: notCur a b = if a > b then b else a and asking for the type which results in the same as the curried version :: Ord a => a -> a -> a  so how could I know (as user of the function) if it there is a curried implementation or not behind?

Comment: @simplesystems If you have another question, do not ask it in the comments, but rather open another question.